# Salesforce Apex: test that callout hasn't been made

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I want to write a unit test that checks that callout hasn't been made from the trigger.
I know how to test if the callout is made correctly - by implementing HttpCalloutMock:

```
global class MyHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        //test HTTPRequest here
    }
}
```

But if no HTTP request is made, then the respond() method won't be called. So this approach doesn't test if the request was made at all.
I need something like this:

```
HTTPRequest.assertNoRequestsHaveBeenMade();
```

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. It turns out that Salesforce has methods `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` that make asynchronous callouts synchronous: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm

After making callouts synchronous it's much easier to test them.