# Salesforce Apex: how to test if trigger was called

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a trigger in Apex. How do I write a unit test that checks if the trigger was called?

```
Account account = new Account(Name='Test account');
insert account;
checkIfInsertTriggerCalled(); // how do I implement this?
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be testing what the trigger does, not just if it was called or not. What does your trigger do?

If you are just trying to see if it inserted then:

```
    Account account = new Account(Name='Test account');
    insert account;
    List<Account> aList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
    system.assertEquals(1,aList.size());
```

side note: I would have just left a comment, but I am a few rep short on this site.
edit: Here is the standard page that gets linked to a lot: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My trigger sends an HTTP request. I'm trying to write a unit tests that checks if the request was made at all (not if it was made correctly, like HttpCalloutMock tutorial teaches). Here is more information in my other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778106/salesforce-apex-test-that-callout-hasnt-been-made